# Ajax form not refreshing - displaying number ' 1 ' after success

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form consisting of 2 input fields on submit the ajax form is suppose to refresh the page and fade in the download button, but it goes to the php file ' download.php ' and displays the digit 1 on top left.

Since im receiving the information from the input I'm guessing 1 is for success and 0 is for fail. how do i stop it from doing this and stay on same page / refresh.

TL;DR - I have a form which submits fine and sends the information to the email ID but it does not refresh the page it goes to the php file and displays digit 1 for success.

Please help.

[HERE is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GcetK/)

followed by my ajax php 'download.php' code, (it does have php opening tag its not showing here for some reason)

```
<?php

$name =$_POST['name'];
$email =$_POST['email'];


// Example 

$HTML         = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" border="0" width="600" style="background:#EEE">
                    <tr>
                    <td>File Download</td>
                    <td></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td>'.$name.'</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td>email:</td>
                    <td>'.$email.'</td>
                    </tr>

                    </table>';

$from = 'emailid@gmail.com';
$to           = "emailid@gmail.com";
$subject     = "Solutions Enquiry by Mr/ Mrs : ".$name;

sendHTMLemail($HTML,$from,$to,$subject);

function sendHTMLemail($HTML,$from,$to,$subject)
{
    // First we have to build our email headers
    // Set out "from" address

    $headers = "From: $from\r\n";

    // Now we specify our MIME version

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    // Create a boundary so we know where to look for
    // the start of the data

    $boundary = uniqid("HTMLEMAIL");

    // First we be nice and send a non-html version of our email

    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".
        "boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";

    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.\r\n\r\n";

    $headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";

    $headers .= "Message-ID: <".$now." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";

    $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode(strip_tags($HTML)));

    // Now we attach the HTML version

    $headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";

    $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($HTML));

    // And then send the email ....

    $sent=mail($to,$subject,"",$headers);

    if($sent)
        echo '1';
    else
        echo '0';

}

?>
```

Comment: I think your ajax call not working you are saying your page rediects to download.php and prints echo value 1 or 0.Please check that one.If ajax call working then it will remain on same page and will give 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2):

In JSFiddle example you'll forget to add jQuery library in sandbox. That's why your code doesn't work. In pure JS there is no selectors like this: $('#...').

The second problem is - you're add

After that i have no any refresh on the page.

UPDATE:
I recommend you to use JSON to translate data from server to client. Add:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

to your $.ajax call and at server side:

```
echo json_encode(array('status'=>1));
```

it help's you to provide more details and data from the server to your client script.

Comment: I tried with dataType: 'json' also itseems to submit the form and go straight to the php file.